# internal hyperlink not working in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, internal

The internal hyperlink scrolling works perfectly in chrome but not in fire fox and internet explorer. Please tell what is the issue,inspect element might come handy to you. Thanks in advance. my website is at my website is http://ec2-54-80-147-161.compute-1.amazonaws.com/index_changed.html

Comment: Please post your relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your main.js line 39,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

Chrome sometimes runs the js in-spite of some errors, and browsers like FF and IE don't. 
Resolve the error and your #links will work across browsers.

As your `main.js` is a minified version, we can't do much to help.

Comment: i am still unable to figure out the problem...if possible your detailed exlanation would be great

Comment: post the un-minified version of your `main.js`,  (create a jsfiddle.net and post the link here)